# Trouble creating a base ViewModel for MvvmCross 5.1.0

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm currently diving into the world of Xamarain with the MvvmCross framework. In my current project I want to make use of a MVVM base ViewModel to be able to reuse some of my code in other ViewModels.

When trying to implement this I've ran into a problem when using the MvxViewModel which supports passing parameters between navigation.

```cs
public abstract class BaseViewModel<TParameter> : MvxViewModel, IMvxViewModel<TParameter> where TParameter : class
{
    protected readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

    public BaseViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public new abstract Task Initialize(TParameter parameter);

}
```

This way I'm able to use the BaseViewModel as following.

```cs
public class ExampleViewModel : BaseViewModel<ExampleParameters>
{
    private ExampleParameters _parameter;

    public ExampleViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {
    }

    public override Task Initialize(ExampleParameters parameter)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => { _parameter = parameter; });
    }
}
```

In this situation I think this is a pretty good solution. The ExampleViewModel even tells me I need to implement the Initialize Task when I've forgotten.

Still this solution is not great in every situation. When I have ViewModel that doesn't require the passing of parameters I still need to specify a parameters object and implement the Initialize method.

```cs
public class ParameterlessViewModel : BaseViewModel<object>
{
    public ParameterlessViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {
    }

    public override Task Initialize(object parameter)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => { });
    }
}
```

When removing the abstract method from the BaseViewModel I wont need to implement the Initialize method but then I won't be forced to implement it when I'm creating a ViewModel that requires the passing of parameters.

The above solution is workable but I'm curious if anyone ran into this same problem and maybe has a better solution? One which is good in both situations without having to setup two BaseViewModel classes.

Kind regards,

Jop Middelkamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for this states: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation

If you have a `BaseViewModel` you might not be able to inherit `MvxViewModel<TParameter>` or `MvxViewModel<TParameter, TResult>` because you already have the `BaseViewModel` as base class. In this case you can implement the following interface:

`IMvxViewModel<TParameter>`, `IMvxViewModelResult<TResult>` or `IMvxViewModel<TParameter, TResult>`

In case you use `TResult` you can just copy the source code into your viewmodel:

```
public override TaskCompletionSource<object> CloseCompletionSource { get; set; }

public override void ViewDestroy()
{
    if (CloseCompletionSource != null && !CloseCompletionSource.Task.IsCompleted && !CloseCompletionSource.Task.IsFaulted)
        CloseCompletionSource?.TrySetCanceled();
    base.ViewDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do we do the add the Interface IMvxViewModel in the base class or the device class, can you give a simple example

```
In this case you can implement the following interface:

IMvxViewModel<TParameter>, IMvxViewModelResult<TResult> or IMvxViewModel<TParameter, TResult>
```